# Can't uninstall anaconda

Tags: anaconda3

On a mac, I am trying to uninstall anaconda3. I also have anaconda navigator installed. I installed anaconda-clean but when I run it from the home directory and I get:
-bash: anaconda-clean: command not found

I can't think of anything else, what can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall Python or remove anaconda directory.

rm -rf anaconda3